# How to get the value of explanatory variable at the point where the response variable is at its maximum? (R)

Tags: r, glm, vertex, quadratic

I have a multivariate binomial GLM with one quadratic (dist_Roads) and multiple linear terms:

`GLM <- glm(formula = Presence ~ dist_NP_boundary + dist_Villages + dist_Water + dist_Grassland + dist_Roads + I(dist_Roads^2), family = "binomial", data = DF)`

All explanatory variables are continuous (in metres), the response variable is binomial (0/1).

The prediction plot generated by code `plot(ggeffects::ggpredict(GLM), facets = TRUE)` looks as follows:

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFUUB.png)

How do I get the value of the quadratic explanatory variable (dist_Roads) at the point where the response variable is at its maximum? I.e. what is the X value at the peak (vertex) of the curve?

How can I calculate it in R?

Comment: Hi Kris. Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't included any code or data, so it's difficult to know how to answer your question.

Comment: Hi Allan, thank you. I have now added the code of my model, not sure what else I should include to make the question more understandable.

Comment: The model shows 5 predictor variables, but a plot like the one you've shown can only have a single predictor variable on the x axis - it's therefore not clear what this plot represents. Is it the marginal effect of roads on the outcome variable? What's the scale on the y axis? Is it log odds or probability? Perhaps including your data with `dput(DF)` and the code that produces the plot would be helpful?

Comment: I have now added a plot that shows all of the predictor variables and the code that I used to produce it. The y axis is probability. I am not including the data as the output of `dput(DF)` is extremely long

Answer (score 2):

We really need some data to demonstrate here, so let's create a similar set, focusing only on `Roads` and `Outcome`:

```r
set.seed(1)

DF <- data.frame(Roads = seq(0, 10000, 100))

DF$Outcome <- rbinom(101, 1, exp(0.005 * DF$Roads - 5e-7 * DF$Roads^2 - 11) /
              (exp(0.005 * DF$Roads - 5e-7 * DF$Roads^2 - 11) + 1))
```

Now let's create our model and plot it to see the shape:

```r
model <- glm(Outcome ~ Roads + I(Roads^2), data = DF, family = binomial)

plot(ggeffects::ggpredict(model, "Roads"))
#> Loading required namespace: ggplot2
```

[image]

To find where the peak occurs, let's look at the coefficients:

```r
coef(model)
#>   (Intercept)         Roads    I(Roads^2) 
#> -1.026831e+01  4.506460e-03 -4.361942e-07
```

Remember, that the maximum probability occurs where the maximum log odds occur, and the formula for log odds is given by these coefficients in the form:

```
#> y = -1.026831e+01  + 4.506460e-03 x - 4.361942e-07 x^2
```

Which means the derivative is given by:

```
#> dy/dx = 4.506460e-03 - 2 * 4.361942e-07 x
```

The only place where dy/dx is 0 is at the maximum point, so we can find the x value at the maximum by rearranging:

```r
#> 0 = 4.506460e-03 - 2 * 4.361942e-07 x
#> 2 * 4.361942e-07 x =  4.506460e-03
#> x = 4.506460e-03 / 2 * 4.361942e-07
```

So the bottom line is that we can simply get the maximum by doing:

```r
maximum_x <- -coef(model)[2] / (2 * coef(model)[3])

maximum_x
#>    Roads 
#> 5165.658
```

To confirm this is the case, let's predict the y value at this x value.

```r
maximum_y <- predict(model, newdata = data.frame(Roads = maximum_x), 
                     type = "response")
```

If we have this right, a point plotted at [maximum_x, maximum_y] should be at the peak of our curve:

```r
plot(ggeffects::ggpredict(model, "Roads")) +
  ggplot2::annotate(geom = "point", x = maximum_x, y = maximum_y, size = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Perfect, it works! Thank you! Would it also be possible to calculate a standard error/confidence interval of the vertex?

Comment: See my answer (too long for comment)

Answer (score 1):

To answer you follow-up question in the comments: you can calculate adjusted predictions at specific values by putting these values into brackets:

```r
# example from Allan's answer
library(ggeffects)
set.seed(1)

DF <- data.frame(Roads = seq(0, 10000, 100))

DF$Outcome <- rbinom(101, 1, exp(0.005 * DF$Roads - 5e-7 * DF$Roads^2 - 11) /
  (exp(0.005 * DF$Roads - 5e-7 * DF$Roads^2 - 11) + 1))

model <- glm(Outcome ~ Roads + I(Roads^2), data = DF, family = binomial)
# value 5165 - see Allan's answer
ggpredict(model, "Roads [5165]")
#> # Predicted probabilities of Outcome
#> 
#> Roads | Predicted |       95% CI
#> --------------------------------
#>  5165 |      0.80 | [0.63, 0.90]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

There's a vignette showing all possibilities to calculate predictions at specific values: https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_effectsatvalues.html

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but this is not really what I meant, sorry if I didn’t explain it clearly. I meant that there is not 100% confidence that the vertex lies at 5,165, right? As I can see from the plot by Allan, the vertex could be also as low as around 3,500 or as high as 6,500 (of the x-axis units), am I right? So basically I was asking whether it is possible to calculate the interval of the x-axis where the vertex lies with 95% probability. Hope this makes sense.